# Sending a notification to my Android from a button press on a website (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, web, messaging

I'm trying to create a button action on a website that will send a notification alert on my phone (Kind of like a pager).

I have a button on a website, and I'm trying to determine what the best way to receive notification of that button press on my Android phone.

Basically:
Button Press on website -> Notification on phone saying button was pressed

How would I implement this in JavaScript, and what would be the best service to do so? Maybe through Google Push, or even another app that I can piggy back off of an existing IM service?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ ??!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can use 2 approaches:

- Push Notifications
- WebSockets

Both of them are workable solutions for your issue

Probably, Push Notifications will be easier and more resource-consuming for mobile app, so let me explain how you can do it

There are lot's of ready-to-go and FREE solutions for push notifications, for example, [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/)

So the flow can be like this:

1. You have a user (you can create it via ConnectyCube dashboard, Users module). So you use this user on both Web and Android ends
2. On Android part, you [authenticate this user](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/authentication-and-users?id=upgrade-session-token-user-login) and [subscribe for push notifications](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/push-notifications)
3. On web part, you also [authenticate this user](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/authentication-and-users?id=upgrade-session-token-user-login). Then [send a push notifications](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/push-notifications?id=send-push-notifications) for himself when a button was pressed

   So Android user will receive a push then